# Messages Dictionary

Tags: node.js, sql-server, angular

We have a conflict in our programming teams when an error raising on the database.

When db facing with error like this:

“Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ... “.

Ui must show understandable messages, like this:

“You cannot Delete this Item. It Used.”

Database team(MS SQL) return pure error message by “raise error” and expects back-end team(Node js) or front-end team(Angular) convert this message to user-understandable messages and show to user. But the back-end team and front-end team say it is not optimized, and db messages must be converted to user-understandable messages in the database.

Are there any standards for this problem?

Comment: System error message miss a major point. In what context of activity did it happen? Creating a record, updating it, deleting it? This might change the message you want to return. Don't rely on System message or numbers which may change. I have a business layer that returns messages based on processing - performing as much useful validation prior to any updates. I don't separate messages into a separate store but embed them in the business layer code. You could have a database table or file for reference and even have placeholders to extend common messages

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility for the content of error messages should not be in the database. For example, the same database might be used from a variety of different applications, with users in different cultures: the database will have no idea what localisation is in place on the particular user interface being used.

Even if your data layer returns a particular error, in different scenarios, this can mean different things. So it is common practice to build a "business" layer on top of the "data" layer. That business layer can make the decision about whether it is a problem or not. This business layer can be re-used by multiple different "user interface" layers (e.g. Web app, Windows app, phone app, etc), or even the business layer of other applications.

But the business layer should only return an indication of what the problem was (including any details which may be relevant). Ultimately, the user interface must be responsible for constructing the error message in a correctly localised way. Most UI layers have a way of storing localised resources for this purpose.